# Splice audio files in iOS

Tags: cocoa-touch, audio

I have a bunch of .wav files that I want to splice in the order they are stored in an `NSMutableArray`. 
I think that I can store the `NSURL` of the audio file (the small one) into the array, and then somehow play them all, in order.

Comment: Please don't delete and repost your questions. What exactly are you looking for? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry. The other post has pretty much wrong cause it didn't even make sense. I need to play sounds randomly, in sequence. I thought I could use AVAudioPlayer, but it causes delay (I need an instantaneous progression). I thought of pasting together the audio files, creating a new large audio file and finally playing that. Is that possible?

Comment: The other idea would be to virtually "listen" to the tracks, record them, and finally play the recorded audio.